# Anonymous innerclass declared in an interface: what is the outerclass?

Tags: java, scjp, ocpjp, open-closed-principle

Consider the following:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private String attribute = "outer";

    class InnerClass {
        private String attribute = "inner";
        public doSomething() {
            System.out.println(this.attribute);
            System.out.println(OuterClass.this.attribute);

        }
    }

}
```

The InnerClass is not static and must be created against an instance of it's outer class.

`new OuterClass().new InnerClass()`

The regular *innerclass* holds a reference to the outer class in which it was created, that is accessible using `Outer.this.myAttribute` (*particularly useful in this case where there is a "naming colision"*

---

When creating an anonymous innerclass, it's the same: the anonymous innerclass created holds a reference to the outer class, this is why when declaring a predicate inside a method (anonymous method-local innerclass), we can still access, inside the innerclass, the variables of the outerclass without having to declare them final (while we should for variables passed as method parameters.

```
public class OuterClass {

  // Do not need to be final because the innerclass keeps a reference to the outerclass
  // even if it's an anonymous innerclass, it's still an innerclass
  private String classAttribute = "classAttribute";

  public Runnable doSomething() {

    // Should be final because the variable lives on the stack and the reference to this object
    // must be copied so that the String object is still accessible when the stack frame is destroyed
    final String localVar = "localVar";

    return new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(classAttribute);
        System.out.println(localVar);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

---

And finally, we can declare constants in an interface, which are implicitly marked public static final. An object can be a constant.
Thus an object created as an anonymous innerclass is a legal constant for an interface.

For exemple, when using Guava, I usually declare in my interface functions and predicates which permits me to leverage the useful Guava functions like `Maps.uniqueIndex(...)`.

```
public interface AlternativeNameable {

  String getAlternativeName();

  Function<AlternativeNameable,String> GET_ALTERNATIVE_NAME = new Function<AlternativeNameable,String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(AlternativeNameable input) {
      return input.getAlternativeName();
    }
  };

}
```

---

So you may ask yourself what is my question? Here it is:

**When declaring an anonymous class as an interface constant (see my last code sample), on which outerclass does the anonymous innerclass holds a reference to?**

Comment: Just tried and there is no attribute at all in the function instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes of interfaces are implicitly static and as such, do not require reference to outer class.

Comment: So you mean that the anonymous innerclass, in this special case, act like a "anonymous static innerclass"? I understand the concept but do you have any link that explains it?

Comment: @SebastienLorber http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5

Answer (score 4):

Fields defined in interfaces [always implicitly have the modifiers `public static final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html). It's a constant, and as such it has no associated outer class.

Also, [member types of interfaces are implicitly public and static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5), which holds true for anonymous classes as well.

Comment: So, the implied `static` is the key here?

Comment: That, and the implied `static` of the interface itself. Interfaces, Enums and Annotations are always `static`.

Comment: This is what I explain. But the fact the reference to that function is static doesn't explain why it doesn't behave like another anonymous innerclass. It is indeed possible to hold a static reference to an anymously declared class which refers to an outerclass.

Comment: @SebastienLorber see Alexei's answer